# serverless issue on running deploy for AppSync: Error: No valid exports main found for 'node_modules/extract-files'

Tags: npm, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm unfamiliar with npm, only used it for basic serverless. Sorry if I'm being noobish.

I'm trying to get a basic serverless-appsync-plugin project up and running, but it turns up the issue in the title. My guess is the plugin cannot be detected, imported, or something along those lines, because when I comment out the plugin line in `serverless.yml`, serverless runs as expected, albeit still not doing what I need it to do.

This is after running `npm install serverless` AND `npm install serverless-appsync-plugin`.

Let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My brew/node/npm stack was out of date, causing some modules to fail to load. Gonna mark as resolved.